# Como pasar variable de Javascript a PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Primero de todo avisar que soy bastante nuevo y novato con PHP.

Hay alguna manera de pasar a PHP una variable de Javascript?
En javascript recibo la variable a traves de un input del usuario.

Dependiendo de la cadena introducida (que sera el nombre de una empresa) se mostrará una tabla cargada de una base de datos donde se muestran datos de esa empresa.
Por lo tanto me gustaría obtener la variable desde javascript para en php seleccionar la base de datos a cargar .

`` $valores= "SELECT * FROM `$variable_javascript`"; ``

El código seria el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Hola @victor por favor puedes colocar el código javascript que estas usando así como el html.

Comment: Si no ocupas que la página no se recargue entonces a través del atributo name del input lo logras

Comment: Debes poner el código aquí y no como imagen amigo, eso de poner imagenes como código se ve muy mal aquí en stackoverflow por diferentes razones, pero como digo, la comunidad siempre preferira codigo antes de imagenes, y pues no les quito la razón, es por una buena razón.

Comment: Asi a resumen rapido, tienes que buscar el valor del button, no del label. sera algo del tipo `var inputt = document.getElementById("btnInput").value;`, pero no estoy del todo seguro

Comment: Lo ideal es que lo que intentes pasar no sea cualquier variable, si no algo que pueda estar en un formulario, algo que haga parte de un formulario, pero bueno tambien se puede mandar cualquier cosa aunque no este en el formulario, pero lo ideal sería que uses solo los datos del formulario para enviarlo y que la demas información extra que le pases solo sea para complementar, mas no para agobiar el servidor con muchas variables, no porque esto sea muy pesado, si no simplemente para mantener el código lo mas simple y clean posible de lado de PHP cuando lo recibas ahí.

Comment: Por ejemplo, no es buena idea que uses una variable de javascript para acceder en php a una base de datos porque para eso existen los formularios,  puedes tener un mismo archivo de conexion donde tengas una función que se encargue de conectar a una base de datos en especifica desde PHP de acuerdo a parametros que tu le pases, ademas, desde el lado de javascript el formulario o los formularios y los input tienen unos campos llamados name, estos contienen información sobre el valor actual de los input, puedes usar esto para reconocer cuál formulario fue el que se envió y apartir de ello.

Comment: Conectarte a una base de datos u otra, en vez de usar una variable en javascript para enviarla a php y hacer la conexion, ya que esto es mas peligroso, de todas maneras amigo lo  bueno es que puedes tener varios formularios en una misma pagina, por lo que puedes crear un formulario diferente para una base de datos diferente, si no que sentido tiene conectarse a una base de datos diferente usando el mismo formulario?, lo digo porque tu solo puedes enviar información a un solo archivo por formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar datos de un archivo `.js` a un archivo `.php` se pueden usar 3 formas, la primera es usar formularios, la segunda es usar formularios y ajax y la tercera es usar solo ajax pero ningún formulario.

Me voy a centrar en la primera, supongamos que tienes un archivo llamado `recibirDatos.php` entonces esta sería la forma de enviar los datos a ese archivo:

```html
<form action = "recibirDatos.php" method = "POST" name = "formulario1" value = "formulario1">
    
    <input type = "text" name = "campo_texto" placeholder = "Escribe algo aquí y será enviado a php...">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Enviar datos!">

</form>
```

Como vemos tenemos un botón tipo submit, que debería estar siempre presente en todos los formularios, ya que es el único botón con el poder de enviar algo a otra parte usando un formulario, **un boton normal no puede realizar esta acción a menos que se lo indiquemos mediante javascript**.

Ahora bien, si le das click al botón submit los datos serán enviados al archivo llamado `recibirDatos.php` donde podremos recibirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

   $nombreFormulario = isset($_POST['formulario1']) ? $_POST['formulario1'] : 'formulario con otro nombre';
   $campoTexto = $_POST['campo_texto'];

   echo $nombreFormulario;
   echo $campoTexto;

   //Aquí entonces es donde compruebas que formulario es el que 
   //Esta enviando los datos, para poder así conectarte ya sea a
   //Una base de datos u otra.
   if($nombreFormulario === 'algunForm1'){

   }else if($nombreFormulario === 'algunForm2'){

   }else{

   }

?>
```

Como vemos, la forma de acceder a los datos en PHP del formulario es mediante el metodo que especificamos en el formulario, en nuestro caso es `POST` pero si hubiese sido `GET` entonces tendrías que acceder con `$_GET` desde php.

Ademas, los atributos `name` de tus input y el formulario son los que serán enviados como información en `POST` o `GET` es decir, donde tu veas que tengas un atributo `name` si ese campo esta rodeado por un formulario enviable, a la hora de enviar estos datos, javascript los enviara enviando un valor por claves parecido a esto:

```
[
   {
      "name del input": value del input
   },
   {
      "name del input": value del input
   }
]
```

Esto a su vez nos dice que el atributo que será enviado como valor en el input es el atributo `value` de los input que aunque no aparezca en el código html que propuse, este cambiara de acuerdo a cuando cambie el valor de los input, por lo cuál realmente no es necesario ponerlo directamente.

Comment: Otra forma que tambien considero que sea posiblemente mejor es tener varios formularios pero diferentes archivos principales donde te conectes a una base de datos diferente y hagas lo que se requiera en el, aunque lo ideal es tener siempre solo 1 base de datos por pagina web... maximo 2.

Answer (score 0):

A ver que te parece esto, yo creo que es lo que quieres, simplemente pruébalo:

```
<?php
    $variable = "<div id='demo'></div>";
    echo $variable;
?>
<input type="text" id="buscador" />
<button onclick="obtenerInput()">Buscar</button>
<script>
    function obtenerInput() {
        var inputt = document.getElementById('buscador').value;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = inputt;
    }
</script>
```